# Is there a way to auto increment ID code of (QA) on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to set up Google Sheets to incorporate ID on the ID column

this is for the google form I designed.

i want it to be like this 
=if(isblank(H3),"", minus(H3,G3))
 but output below
I say expect the output of example: QA+Date+001
ie: QA20190324001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code reads the whole sheet then checks for `ID` in every row. If `ID` is not present, creates one based on `QA+Date+Number` formula. Then writes rows back to sheet. Try this.

```
var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0; // which col to increment
var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1; // how many header rows

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange(); // get sheet range
var values = range.getValues(); // get sheet values

var today = new Date(); // todays date
var autoIncStart = 1; // start auto increment at this number
var lengthOfID = 3; // length of ID
var prefixID = 'QA'; // ID prefix

for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < values.length; row++) {
  var id = values[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
  if (('' + id).length === 0) {
    // no id present, create one and set
    // comment out below lines if no operation is needed when id is empty
    id = prefixID;
    id += today.getFullYear() + zeroPad(today.getMonth() + 1, 2) + today.getDate();
    id += zeroPad(autoIncStart, lengthOfID);
    values[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN] = id;
    autoIncStart++;
  }
}

// write values back to sheet
range.setValues(values);

// zero pad a number up to given length
function zeroPad(num, length) {
  var str = '' + num;
  while (str.length < length) str = '0' + str;
  return str;
}
```

Comment: but if it's blank, I want to no characters

Comment: I want to try if(isblank(C2), "" , QA20190325001) it doesn't work